# How to implement Cryptarithmetic using Constraint Satisfaction in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, constraint-satisfaction

I'll start by explaining what a cryptarithmetic problem is, through an example:

```
  T W O
+ T W O
F O U R
```

We have to assign a digit [0-9] to each letter such that no two letters share the same digit and it satisfies the above equation.

One solution to the above problem is:

```
   7 6 5   
+  7 6 5       
 1 5 3 0
```

There are two ways to solve this problem, one is brute force, this will work but it's not the optimal way. The other way is using constraint satisfaction.

**Solution using Constraint Satisfaction**
We know that R will always be even because its 2 * O
this narrows down O's domain to {0, 2, 4, 6, 8}
We also know that F can't be anything but 1, since F isn't an addition of two letters, it must be getting its value from carry generated by *T + T = O*
This also implies that *T + T > 9*, only then will it be able to generate a carry for F;
This tells us that *T > 4* {5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
And as we go on doing this, we keep on narrowing down the domain and this helps us reduce time complexity by a considerable amount.

The concept seems easy, but I'm having trouble implementing it in C++. Especially the part where we generate constraints/domain for each variable. Keep in mind that there are carries involved too.

EDIT: I'm looking for a way to generate a domain for each variable using the concept I stated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: First of all welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: As for how to solve your problem, any complex problem can be broken down into smaller and simpler sub-problems. Do this sub-division until all problems are as simple as they can be and can'be be further sub-divided. Then solve and implement each little sub-problem one by one, with testing in between to make sure it works as intended. When you put it all together you have solved the original complex problem.

Comment: Is it an option to convert the whole thing to SAT/SMT and use z3 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved it using backtracking

My approach here was to smartly brute force it, I recursively assign every possible value [0-9] to each letter and check if there is any contradiction.

Contradictions can be one of the following:

- Two or more letters end up having the same value.
- Sum of letters don't match the value of the result letter.
- Sum of letters is already assigned to some letter.

As soon as a contradiction occurs, the recursion for that particular combination ends.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

vector<string> words, wordOg;
string result, resultOg;
bool solExists = false;

void reverse(string &str){
    reverse(str.begin(), str.end());
}

void printProblem(){
    cout<<"\n";
    for(int i=0;i<words.size();i++){
        for(int j=0;j<words[i].size();j++){
            cout<<words[i][j];
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }
    cout<<"---------\n";
    for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
        cout<<result[i];
    }
    cout<<"\n";
}

void printSolution(unordered_map<char, int> charValue){
    cout<<"\n";
    for(int i=0;i<words.size();i++){
        for(int j=0;j<words[i].size();j++){
            cout<<charValue[wordOg[i][j]];
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }
    cout<<"---------\n";
    for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
        cout<<charValue[resultOg[i]];
    }
    cout<<"\n";
}

void solve(int colIdx, int idx, int carry, int sum,unordered_map<char, int> charValue, vector<int> domain){


    if(colIdx<words.size()){
        if(idx<words[colIdx].size()){
            char ch = words[colIdx][idx];
            if(charValue.find(ch)!=charValue.end()){
                solve(colIdx + 1, idx, carry, sum + charValue[ch], charValue, domain);
            }
            else{
                for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
                    if(i==0 && idx==words[colIdx].size()-1) continue;
                    if(domain[i]==-1){
                        domain[i] = 0;
                        charValue[ch] = i;
                        solve(colIdx + 1, idx, carry, sum + i, charValue, domain);
                        domain[i] = -1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else solve(colIdx + 1, idx, carry, sum, charValue, domain);
    }
    else{
        if(charValue.find(result[idx])!=charValue.end()){
            if(((sum+carry)%10)!=charValue[result[idx]]) return;
        }
        else{
            if(domain[(sum + carry)%10]!=-1) return;
            domain[(sum + carry)%10] = 0;
            charValue[result[idx]] = (sum + carry)%10;
        }
        carry = (sum+carry)/10;
        if(idx==result.size()-1 && (charValue[result[idx]]==0 || carry == 1)) return;
        if(idx+1<result.size()) solve(0, idx+1, carry, 0, charValue, domain);
        else{
            solExists = true;
            printSolution(charValue);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    unordered_map<char, int> charValue;
    vector<int> domain(10,-1);

    int n;
    cout<<"\nEnter number of input words: ";
    cin>>n;
    cout<<"\nEnter the words: ";
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        string inp;
        cin>>inp;
        words.push_back(inp);
    }
    cout<<"\nEnter the resultant word: ";
    cin>>result;

    printProblem();

    wordOg = words;
    resultOg = result;

    reverse(result);
    for(auto &itr: words) reverse(itr);

    solve(0, 0, 0, 0, charValue, domain);

    if(!solExists) cout<<"\nNo Solution Exists!";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This kind of problem is a good application for generic constraint programming packages like Google's open source OR-Tools. (See https://developers.google.com/optimization and https://developers.google.com/optimization/cp/cryptarithmetic).

The package is written in c++, so it should be a good match for you.

Then programming the problem is as simple as this (sorry, since I work with OR-Tools in c#, this is c# code, but the c++ code will look pretty much the same)

```
public void initModel(CpModel model)
        {
            // Make variables
            T = model.NewIntVar(0, 9, "T");
            W = model.NewIntVar(0, 9, "W");
            O = model.NewIntVar(0, 9, "O");
            F = model.NewIntVar(0, 9, "F");
            U = model.NewIntVar(0, 9, "U");
            R = model.NewIntVar(0, 9, "R");

            // Constrain the sum
            model.Add((2 * (100 * T + 10 * W + O)) == (1000 * F + 100 * O + 10 * U + R));

            // Make sure the variables are all different
            model.AddAllDifferent(decisionVariables);

            // The leading digit shouldn't be 0
            model.Add(T != 0);
            model.Add(F != 0);
        }
```

and then calling the `Solve` method.

In the constraint for the sum, the operators* + and == are all overridden in the package to create objects that can be used by the model to enforce the constraint.

This is the start of the output which enumerates the solution

```
Solution #0: time = 0,00 s;
 T = 8
 W = 6
 O = 7
 F = 1
 U = 3
 R = 4

Solution #1: time = 0,01 s;
 T = 8
 W = 4
 O = 6
 F = 1
 U = 9
 R = 2

Solution #2: time = 0,01 s;
 T = 8
 W = 3
 O = 6
 F = 1
 U = 7
 R = 2

Solution #3: time = 0,01 s;
 T = 9
 W = 3
 O = 8
 F = 1
 U = 7
 R = 6
```

And here's the complete code including solution printing and Main method for the execution:

```
using Google.OrTools.Sat;
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace SO69626335_CryptarithmicPuzzle
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Google.OrTools.Sat.CpModel model = new CpModel();
                ORModel myModel = new ORModel();
                myModel.initModel(model);
                IntVar[] decisionVariables = myModel.decisionVariables;

                // Creates a solver and solves the model.
                CpSolver solver = new CpSolver();
                VarArraySolutionPrinter solutionPrinter = new VarArraySolutionPrinter(myModel.variablesToPrintOut);
                solver.SearchAllSolutions(model, solutionPrinter);
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Number of solutions found: {0}",
                    solutionPrinter.SolutionCount()));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
                throw;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("OK");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    class ORModel
    {
        IntVar T;
        IntVar W;
        IntVar O;
        IntVar F;
        IntVar U;
        IntVar R;

        public void initModel(CpModel model)
        {
            // Make variables
            T = model.NewIntVar(0, 9, "T");
            W = model.NewIntVar(0, 9, "W");
            O = model.NewIntVar(0, 9, "O");
            F = model.NewIntVar(0, 9, "F");
            U = model.NewIntVar(0, 9, "U");
            R = model.NewIntVar(0, 9, "R");

            // Constrain the sum
            model.Add((2 * (100 * T + 10 * W + O)) == (1000 * F + 100 * O + 10 * U + R));

            // Make sure the variables are all different
            model.AddAllDifferent(decisionVariables);

            // The leading digit shouldn't be 0
            model.Add(T != 0);
            model.Add(F != 0);
        }

        public IntVar[] decisionVariables
        {
            get
            {
                return new IntVar[] { T, W, O, F, U, R };
            }
        }

        public IntVar[] variablesToPrintOut
        {
            get
            {
                return decisionVariables;
            }
        }
    }

    public class VarArraySolutionPrinter : CpSolverSolutionCallback
    {
        private int solution_count_;
        private IntVar[] variables;

        public VarArraySolutionPrinter(IntVar[] variables)
        {
            this.variables = variables;
        }
        public override void OnSolutionCallback()
        {
            // using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\temp\GoogleSATSolverExperiments.txt", true, Encoding.UTF8))
            using (TextWriter sw = Console.Out)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(String.Format("Solution #{0}: time = {1:F2} s;",
                solution_count_, WallTime()));
                foreach (IntVar v in variables)
                {
                    sw.Write(
                    String.Format(" {0} = {1}\r\n", v.ShortString(), Value(v)));
                }
                solution_count_++;
                sw.WriteLine();
            }
            if (solution_count_ >= 10)
            {
                StopSearch();
            }
        }
        public int SolutionCount()
        {
            return solution_count_;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A full solution is *way* out of scope for a simple SO question, but I can sketch what you would need.

First, generate new letters for the carries:

```
   0 T W O
   0 T W O
+  Z Y X V
   F O U R
```

You can then generate a `std::map<char, std::set<int>>` containing all the options. The letters have the standard range {0..9}, V is {0}, Z is {1} and Y and X have {0..1}.

Next, you need to encode the additions into a set of clauses.

```
enum class Op { Equal, SumMod10, SumDiv10, Even, Odd };
struct clause { Op op; std::vector<Var> children; };

std::vector<clause> clauses{
{Equal, { 'Z' , 'F'}},
{SumMod10, {'O', 'T', 'T', 'Y'}}, // O = (T+T+Y) mod 10
{SumMod10, {'U', 'W', 'W', 'X'}},
{SumMod10, {'R', 'O', 'O', 'V'}},
{SumDiv10, {'F', 'T', 'T', 'Y'}}, // F is the carry of T+T+Y
{SumDiv10, {'O', 'W', 'W', 'X'}},
{SumDiv10, {'U', 'O', 'O', 'V'}},
};
```

Then the fun part begins: you need to create a calculation that will try to simplify the constraints using the knowledge it has.
For example, `{SumMod10, {'U', 'O', 'O', 'V'}}` can be simplified to `{SumMod10, {'U', 'O', 'O', 0}}` since `V=0`.
Sometimes a clause can reduce the range of a variable, for example the `{Equal, {'Z', 'F'}}` constraint can immediately reduce the range of `F` to {0,1}.

Next, you need to teach your system about basic algebraic equalities for furhter simplification, such as:
`{SumMod10, {A, 0, C}} === {SumMod10, {A, C, 0}} === {Equal, {A,C}}`
and even more abstract things like "if A >= 5 and B >= 5 then A+B >= 10" or "if A is even and B is even then A + B is also even".

Finally, your system needs to be able to assume hypotheses and disprove them, or prove that a hypothesis is true no matter what, like you did in your post.
For example, assuming that R is odd would mean that O + O is odd, which can only happen if O is odd and even at the same time. Therefore R must be even.

At the end of the day, you will have implemented not only a formal system for describing and evaluating boolean clauses in the numbers domain, you will also have a goal-driven solution engine to go with it. If this is more than just an idle musing, I would strongly look into adoption an SMT system to solve this for you or at least learning Prolog and expressing your problem there.